# What pokemon are in what Raid tier?

Tags: pokemon-go

Apparently there are different tiers of PokeRaids (see screenshot). Does the Pokémon you fight depend on which tier? And if so, which Pokémon belong to which tier?

[image: screenshot of tiers]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/6j6idf/raid_tier_boss_list/) list:

## Tier 1 Gyms:

- Quilava
- Bayleef
- Magikarp
- Croconaw

## Tier 2 Gyms:

- Electabuzz
- Muk
- Magmar
- Weezing
- Exeggutor

## Tier 3 Gyms

- Alakazam
- Arcanine
- Flareon
- Jolteon
- Vaporeon
- Machamp
- Gengar

## Tier 4 Gyms:

- Blastoise
- Charizard
- Venusaur
- Rhydon
- Lapras
- Snorlax
- Tyranitar

## Tier 5 Gyms:

These are apparently going to be Legendary Pokemon, but TBC and N/A